# WPF Horizontal tab control like microsoft nav 2017

Tags: wpf

Anyone has some idea about how to create horizontal tab control like below image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsi2D.png)

Comment: Please show an image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "ribbon".
Check this link for more information on the subject
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf/

And some general information for learn in depth
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx

Always search before you ask!!!

Comment: Dear friend its not ribbon, as i mentioned in the image its just like expander.